# Send custom data to Prometheus

Tags: python, prometheus

I am new to Prometheus and I would like to send some custom metrics to Prometheus. I am using this [client lib](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#wsgi).

```
from prometheus_client import make_wsgi_app
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def prometheus_config():
    app = make_wsgi_app()
    httpd = make_server('', 1618, app)
    httpd.serve_forever()


def start_prometheus_server():
    threading.Thread(target=prometheus_config).start()enter code here
```

I have started service for Prometheus.

1. How could I now up `/custom` endpoint?
2. How can I send there my
   custom data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register in registry custom collector class:

```
class CustomCollector(object):
    def collect(self):
        yield GaugeMetricFamily('my_gauge', 'Help text', value=7)
        c = CounterMetricFamily('my_counter_total', 'Help text', labels=['foo'])
        c.add_metric(['bar'], 1.7)
        c.add_metric(['baz'], 3.8)
        yield c

REGISTRY.register(CustomCollector())
```

Then use this registry when start the server:

```
app = make_wsgi_app(REGISTRY)
httpd = make_server('', 1618, app)
```